# Error Deserialization JSON in .NET Core WorkerService

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

We're developing a worker service in .NET Core 7. The service reads JSON from a file and deserializes it into a model.

The model is:

```
public class MWRoot
{
    public string? Authority { get; set; }
    public string? ShopNo { get; set; }
}
```

And the Json is :

```
{
    "Authority": "lbg",
    "ShopNo": "1397"
}
```

The code:

```
 using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonfile, true))
 {
     string json = r.ReadToEnd();        
     MWRoot mwProperty = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MWRoot>(json);                    
 }
```

When debugging the program in Visual Studio 2022, there are no problems, but when using it as a Windows Service (`sc create "ServiceName" binpath=.....`) it throws this exception:

> Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported.

Comment: Running as a Windows Service has zero impact on JSON deserialization. Something else is going wrong, provide a [mre].

Comment: Your deployed binaries likely do not match the binaries you're debugging with, or else the error you're getting is actually happening on a different line. Clean the project, rebuild it, publish it properly, then check how the published code runs from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Thx to Jeroen.

I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service publishing the WorkerService. Which meant that not all necessary files were copied to the target directory [image: Publish Settings]

When removing checkbox in Produce single file the service worked.